# adding arrays of numbers into html form input and displaying the calculated result

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, wordpress

I have an array having 2-3 titles. eg. 'Get 20% Off' , 'Receive 40% Savings' , 'Grab 10% discounts' etc. I would like to get the numeric value before '%' sign. and pass this numeric value into a html form as inputs. and in return the form would calculate a percentage amount. and display all the results.

Right now i have managed to make this work for a single title. but i am not able to get a array of titles.

my code is as follows -

//code for getting all the titles //putting it into an array called '$array'

```
foreach($array as $str) {
if(preg_match('/(\d+)\%/i' ,$str,$m)) {
             echo $m[1],"\n"; ?>

<?php  }
} ?>
```

//the above code extracts the amount before the percentage off sign. and the below code passes it as a input to the form (name=a). and other input (name=b) is coming from a different source. thats working fine. for calculation consider that input to be 100. I would need to calculate the percent value w.r.t 100. for eg- if input a is 5, then another input b is 100. the value to be outputted would be 5.

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" name="a" value="<?php echo $m[1]; ?>" size=5> 
  <input class="budget-sidebar" type="text" name="b" id="amount" size=5>
```

the below html is used for displaying the calculated value and submitting the form.

```
<input type="text" name="total1" value="ans1" size=5 maxlength=4>
  <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calc1(this.form)">
  </form>
```

the below javascript function is responsible to take the inputs and calculate the value and displaying it.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function calc1(form) {
a = form.a.value/100;
b = a*form.b.value;
form.total1.value = b;
}
//  End -->
</script>
```

i have posted a similar question requesting for different suggestions & this is supposed to be a different query. thanks.

Comment: I'd not understand what are you asking?

Comment: you are getting error in calculating or displaying??

Comment: i am able to display result for a single string. i would want to display result for 2-3 strings from an array.

Answer (score 1):

try to convert form value to integer before performing calculation

```
function calc1(form) {
    a = parseInt(form.a.value, 10)/100;
    b = a* parseInt(form.b.value, 10);
    form.total1.value = b;
}
```

And you will have to round the value to avoid to get strange value

[Edit]:

And to get multi string some thing like this will may work (no test sorry)

```
// php
$values = array();
foreach($array as $str) {
    if(preg_match('/(\d+)\%/i' ,$str,$m)) {
        $values[] = $m[1];
    }
}

// for html
<form name="form1">
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="a<?php echo $i ?>" value="<?php echo $values[i]; ?>" size=5> 
    <?php} ?>
    <input class="budget-sidebar" type="text" name="b" id="amount" size=5>

// javascript
function calc1(form) {
    var i = 0, a = 0;
    while (form["a" + i]) {
        a += parseInt(form["a" + i].value, 10);
        i++;
    }
    b = a/100 * parseInt(form.b.value, 10);
    form.total1.value = b;
}
```

Comment: thanks peernohell, but i am not able to calculate the result for multiple strings.